# PhoneGap 2.4.0, Windows Phone 8, change location of index.html

Tags: cordova, indexing, location, windows-phone-8, rename

Quick question (hopefully). How do i change the location (www/index.html) of the index.html in a "Windows Phone 8"-app? I'm using PhoneGap 2.4.0.

First time messing about with a Windows Phone 8 app so I'm sorry if the answer is obvious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the MainPage constructor in MainPage.cs

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CordovaView.StartPageUri = new Uri("/www/html/initializeconnection.html", UriKind.Relative);
        this.CordovaView.Loaded += CordovaView_Loaded;
    }
```

Comment: You can actually add StartPageUri="some uri" to xaml file as CordovaView attribute